# backgroundColor hiding the clearButtonMode's X in Input of react-native-elements

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

```
  <Input
    autoFocus
    containerStyle={styles.search}
    placeholder="Search..."
    onChangeText={this.Search}
    inputContainerStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 0 }}
    clearButtonMode="always"
    placeholderTextColor={theme.firstColor.hex}
  />

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  search: {
    backgroundColor: "white", // <--- This is hiding the X button
    paddingLeft: 20,
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderColor: theme.secondColor,
    width: 300,
    height: 50,
  }
});
```

Basically, backgroundColor: "white" is hiding the clearButtonMode's X button, is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Maybe try author's [workaround ?](https://github.com/react-native-elements/react-native-elements/issues/2190#issuecomment-557174793)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my researching, `react-native-elements` does not support `Input` clear button styling, yet.

So, I think you should try to customize it, something like this:

```html
import {Icon, Input} from 'react-native-elements';

<Input
    ...
    rightIcon={
        <Icon
            containerStyle={{
                marginRight: normalize(10)
            }}
            name={'ios-close'} type={'ionicon'} color="#7384B4" size={22}
            onPress={() => {
                this.setState({email: ''});
            }}
        />
    }
/>
```

Hope it help ^^.

Comment: Anyhow, will choose this as an answer since it's a workaround that fixed my problem! Thank you.